# ESLint Unable to Resolve TypeScript Path Aliases in Node.js Project

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am working on a Node.js project using TypeScript, and I have set up path aliases in my `tsconfig.json`. However, ESLint is unable to resolve these path aliases, resulting in the error: `Unable to resolve path to module '@/config.js'`. I've tried configuring ESLint to recognize the TypeScript path mappings, but the issue persists.

##### Project Details:

- **Node.js Version**: 18.18.1
- **TypeScript Version**: 5.2.1
- **ESLint Version**: 8.54.0

##### Relevant Configurations:

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@sourceService/*": ["./src/modules/source/*"],
      "@crawlService/*": ["./src/modules/crawl/*"],
      "@searchService/*": ["./src/modules/search/*"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    // ... other options ...
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./test"]
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  // ... other configurations ...
  "settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": true,
      "typescript": {
        "alwaysTryTypes": true,
        "project": "./"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example Import Statement Causing the Issue**:

```js
import { CONFIG } from '@/config.js';
```

1. Ensured `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` is installed.
2. Configured ESLint to use TypeScript's path resolutions.
3. Restarted ESLint and the development environment.
4. Verified the existence and correct path of `src/config.js`.

Despite these attempts, ESLint still fails to resolve the path aliases. Does anyone have suggestions on how to configure ESLint correctly to recognize TypeScript path aliases in this scenario?

Now everything building correctly, but I'm still getting this underscore error in this project, in other project with same packages, and config I do not  get this errors. (the project it works is npm package with no server etc, just pure javascript / node with typescript and zod package (I wrote javascript/node because this package can be run on client and server side)

I can edit `settings` to make them look like this:

```
  "settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
///////////////////
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".ts", ".d.ts", ".tsx"]
    },
///////////////////
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": true,
      "node": true
    }
  }
```

and underscore errors disappears but when I type

`npx eslint --fix .` in my root dit then I recive this error saying:

```js
TypeError: "settings" for node must be an array
Occurred while linting C:\Users\...
Rule: "import/default"
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing and re-opening VSCode manuall did not work (It was re-opening project probably with some cache(?). It started working after opening fresh VSC instance.